# Jquery Tags-input add tags to asp:textbox from prompting with percent sign value Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: %

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-tags-input

I have a prompting to add text to `asp:textbox` with `percent-sign` from Javascript and try to escaped % to string

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtValue" Enabled="true" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>


     sql = prompt("Enter Condition");
                if (sql != null) {
                    var sqlcode = cond.concat(" like ", " \'\%]", sql, "\%\' ");
                    $('#<%= txtValue.ClientID %>').addTag(sqlcode);
                }
```

but this still shown me

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: %test%

`jquery-tags-input` initialize

```
   <script>
        function onAddTag(tag) {
            alert("Added a tag: " + tag);
        }

        function onRemoveTag(tag) {
            alert("Removed a tag: " + tag);
        }

        function onChangeTag(input, tag) {
            alert("Changed a tag: " + tag);
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
             $('#<%= txtSQL.ClientID %>').tagsInput({
              width: 'auto',
              'delimiter': ['  '],
              defaultText: "",
unique:false,

              onAddTag: function (elem, elem_tags) {
                  var languages = ['or', 'and'];
                  $('.tag', elem_tags).each(function () {
                      if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp('\\b(' + languages.join('|') + ')\\b')) >= 0)
                          $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
                  });
              },
              onChange: function (elem, elem_tags) {
                  var languages = ['or', 'and'];
                  $('.tag', elem_tags).each(function () {
                      if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp('\\b(' + languages.join('|') + ')\\b')) >= 0)
                          $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
                  });
              }


          });

  });
</script>
```

this happened with `'` `Singlequote` too

how can I escaped them to String, I try to use double backslash `\\` but it's just use for metacharacters on input ID I can't use with value.

Comment: This is not a valid ID by any chance. This might result in a valid ID if preprocessed by some server-side thingie, but backslashes won't achieve that (quite the opposite). If you are serving a .js file, chances are the server doesn't know it's supposed to transform it somehow first.

Comment: So I try to add text to text input but there's same error :) @JanDvorak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my solutions by delete these proc

```
onAddTag: function (elem, elem_tags) {
    var languages = ['or', 'and'];
    $('.tag', elem_tags).each(function () {
        if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp('\\b(' + languages.join('|') + ')\\b')) >= 0)
            $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
    });
},
onChange: function (elem, elem_tags) {
     var languages = ['or', 'and'];
     $('.tag', elem_tags).each(function () {
        if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp('\\b(' + languages.join('|') + ')\\b')) >= 0)
           $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
     });
}
```

Then it worked like a charm :)